# Point layer draws very slowly after using ArcPy to add to mxd?

Tags: arcpy, performance, mxd, map-drawing

I am using an ArcPy script to add a point feature class to an mxd.  The map document will draw this layer very slowly, approximately 50 to 100 points per second.  If I remove the layer and add it manually, it draws about 20 times faster. the code I use is:

```
FeatureClass = "path\to\my\fc.gdb\featureclass"
layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("FeatureClass")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(DataFrame, layer, "BOTTOM")
```

I use this same code to add a polygon layer and it draws just fine.
I've tried using this method in an unrelated mxd with an unrelated layer and it drew fine.  I've also tried different symbologies, including the Arc standard, and running this on different computers with the same result.

Comment: It could be something with a specific mxd.  Can you reproduce this by opening up a blank mxd and executing that same code?

Comment: My coworkers and I use this script about 10 times a day, on 3 different computers.  I've run it both on my local machine and over our in house server, with the same result every time.  And just to be clear, that is with quite a few different mxd's.

Comment: Gotcha, I think I just spotted what was slowing it down.  See my answer below.

Comment: How many points does your feature class have?

Comment: the point feature class can have between 50 and 10000 points.  Obviously this isn't too much of an issue on the low end, but I've noticed that the issue is still there, and it definitely is an issue on the high end.

Comment: Just as additional information, I've tried this with all sorts of symbology and display settings without effect.

Comment: Does it do this with every point feature class you try to add (e.g. feature classes completely unrelated)? I can't reproduce this with 10.4.1. What version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: I am using 10.3  I tried it with an unrelated feature class and it came in fine.  This makes me wonder about my gdb, which is built by a model that I don't have access to.  Part of my script loads data into this gdb, but I didn't think that was the problem because if I remove the slow layer from the map and re add it, it solves the problem.  Any thing I should inspect in my GDB?

Comment: If your feature class varies in record count by that much regularly, it could be an index problem or could be the gdb just needs a compress.  Both of these could be added separately into your script to test

Comment: @CraigT Please **[edit]** your question to include extra information and responses, rather than as comments.  Potential answerers don't always see all the comments - all relevant info should be in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You actually do not have to use `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management()` first, you can just create an `arcpy.mapping.Layer` from the feature class itself:

```
FeatureClass = "path\to\my\fc.gdb\featureclass"
layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(FeatureClass)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(DataFrame, layer, "BOTTOM")
```

This should add the layer instantly.  Maybe your bottleneck was waiting for the make feature layer command to finish.

Comment: The layer was being added anyway, although now that I try it this way it seems that I don't need that line of code.  However, the original problem that the layer draws slowly still exists.

Comment: That is strange.  I misunderstood as I thought you meant there was a delay before it even started drawing (from the make feature layer).  I don't know what would be different about the layer once it's in the map when it was added manually vs Python.  It should behave the same, regardless of how it was added.